# ASP.NET MVC area routing does not recognize id

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an asp.net MVC project containing 4 areas.

My problem starts when i try to put a parameter in one of my actions in a controller that belongs to an area.

My RouteConfig:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

My AreaRegistration:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "bg_default",
                "bg/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller="jde",action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Here is one action in my controller. when i debug it the _what string parameters gets the name of the action "NullifiedInvoicesFix".

when i type mysite/bg/Jde/NullifiedIncoicesFix/update , _what is NOT "update" but "NullifiedInvoicesFix"

```
public ActionResult NullifiedInvoicesFix(string _what)
        {
            if (_what == "view")
            {
                ViewBag.F4211 = this.db.Query<dynamic>(@"SELECT sdivd,SDDOC,SDDCT,SDDOCO,SDDCTO,SDODOC,SDODCT FROM F4211 WHERE SDDCT IN
                                                    ('E8','E9','E0','EP','EC','EB','ED') AND SDODOC <> SDDOC AND
                                                    SDODOC<>0 order by sdivd");    
            } 
            return View();
```

Comment: where does _what should come from ? I don't see it in your route definition. Did you ensure you register your areas before your more general routes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rename _what to id:

```
 public ActionResult NullifiedInvoicesFix(string id)
```